# Angular updates form control value on value change

Tags: angular, subscribe, form-control

I am able to subscribe to a `formControl.valueChanges` to see the new value being set to the `formControl`. But now if I need to further update this new value inside the subscription, how do you do it? i.e. when a formControl value is changed, I need to further update it so that the formControl has my updated version of that value.

```
// not working code
this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.formControl.value = value + " changed");
```

Comment: Use `setValue`: this.formControl.setValue(value)

Comment: If you want to do something when the user changes the form control's value, you can use the `(change)` event.

Comment: @Isaac Wouldn't `setValue` trigger the subscription again in a cyclic manner?

Comment: Yes, valueChanges emits an event everytime the value changes.

Comment: @Isaac so that means it is not possible to do it inside subscribe?

Comment: It's not possible to change the value the way you're doing it in your code because you have to use `setValue`. I've no idea what your use case is. I don't know if you want to change the value in a specific case that could constitute a condition that would break the cycle, for example. In my second comment I suggested using the `(change)` event if you want to do something only when the user changes the value, and not when the value is changed programatically. You want to change the value subscribing to `valueChanges`. I told you how, but I'm not implying it's a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to stop valueChanges emission on setValue call. We can set options config to [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#methods) method

```
this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  this.formControl.setValue(`${value} changed`,{emitEvent:false});
 }
```